# How can I model this schema in MySQL?

Tags: databases, mysql

I want to create a schema that reflects the following relationships, and I'm trying to do this in MySQL Workbench. (I'm no DB expert)

- I have 3 environments - sandbox, staging, and production
- I release a product version in each environment, e.g., `sb-1.0.0` for sandbox, `st-1.0.0` for staging, and `pr-1.0.0` for production. I can have multiple releases per environment, but there can only be ONE version that's currently released in each environment.
- Each product version in each environment contains a set of services, same set of services in all the environments, but differing in their version numbers. So `sb-1.0.0 = [svc1-2.0.0, svc2-2.0.0], st-1.0.0 = [svc1-1.0.0, svc2-2.0.0], and pr-1.0.0 = [svc1-1.0.0, svc2-1.0.0]`. As you can see, I have the same 2 services in all environments, but the service versions can be different (or the same) in each  environment.

I want to accomplish multiple things.

- I want to be able to create new releases in each environment, with each release containing the set of services and corresponding versions. So I want to be able to create a `pr-2.0.0 = [svc1-2.0.0, svc2-1.0.0]` version.
- I want to be able to query my DB for version `pr-1.0.0` and know all the services and their respective versions in this particular release.
- I want to have the notion of a "current version" and a "desired version" for each service in each environment.
- I want to be be able to then run a script (Kubernetes?) to release each service and their respective version based on the query.
- I want to be able to extend it to more environments, e.g., add a UAT environment.

So how do I model my DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to credit Max N for making me think about another solution.

In fact I already have the solution, right in front of me. We're a Gradle shop, and our `build.gradle` files contains our dependencies. So when I release a version, I know exactly what services+versions I need for this version. Since we have branches corresponding to our environments, I the services I need in each environment. So when I just need to

- I need to Git tag every time we do a build, including the tools that did the build
- When deploying, I then need to deploy above tag, which includes code + tools

Thanks again Max N.

Comment: I'm here to help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about what happen with stale/old data??

- Each new version creates a ton of new entries.
- Management becomes a nightmare
- the DB becomes a SPOF(single point of failure).

---

## Better Solution: Service discovery

The better solution would be to use a Service discovery System and annote each Service with their version and the environment as a Metadata tag. This keeps the System more manageble.

## More Help

IMHO, sticking Linux Code into a **Docker Image** and run multiple copies of it, is the best way of getting a immutable infrastructure up and running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that. Anything to simplify our release/versioning system will be good.

Comment: I mean, how is the linux kernel packaged? In linux, a kernel version has a set of packages (and their versions) it needs correct? I guess I'm after something like that, or even like Gem for Ruby, or brew on a Mac.

Comment: Kernel and User package are two different things. You could use Docker images.